# Is it possible to enable specific Elliptic Curve Cryptography (ECC) cipher suites on the Hololens 1?

Tags: hololens, windows-mixed-reality

I am trying to start a secure MQTT connection using MQTTNet on the Hololens 1. I managed to load all necessary certificates, however, the connection fails because the EC-Curve sepc521r1 is required. On a Win10 desktop system, this can be enabled using the Powershell command  `Enable-TlsEccCurve "NistP521"`.

Can I somehow enable this curve on the Hololens?

Comment: There is currently no public document stating that HoloLens OS supports this ECC Curve. I will discuss with the internal team and get back to you.

Comment: @Hernando-MSFT Thanks! We will be soon upgrading to a Hololens 2 (which has Core OS?), is there any information if the above ECC curve is supported there? Thanks for your help! BR Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked to the team a bit further and it doesn’t appear we have a CSP that would enable this. Could you submit a feature request via feedback hub on new feature request to be considered in future releases of HoloLens OS and devices? If it’s a hot impacted feature, it will be possible to be given priority to jump in the development schedule.

For how to post feedback request, you can follow this doc: [Send feedback to Microsoft with the Feedback Hub app](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4021566/windows-10-send-feedback-to-microsoft-with-feedback-hub-app).